# Truncate/delete tables for non-owner schema

Tags: oracle, truncate

Is it possible to give truncate rights to user A to truncate tables owned by user B?

But I should be able to truncate each table of B by A as per wish.

Some procedures would be needed I suppose? Kindly help!!

Platform - Oracle

Answer (score 3):

You can give `DROP ANY TABLE` system privilege to A, then he will be able to truncate everything in any schema (not just in B's though) .

If you don't want to do that, a simple stored procedure created by B will do the job (procedure or function in Oracle are by default executed with definer rights) . Then you give need `execute` permission to A on this procedure. 
For instance,

```
create procedure truncate_my_table(tab_name varchar2)
as
begin
    execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || tab_name;
end;
```

You may also want to add parameter validation (for example,  I'd do `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(DBMS_ASSERT.QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME(tab_name))` ) , error handling and logging to the procedure.

Comment: What is that tab name? Is it the table name? And why do we mention as varchar there? What if the user has 1000 tables? And user b needs to truncate only some tables of it?

Comment: user b calls this procedure to truncate table :  `execute a.truncate_my_table('table_1');`